# Каким образом в Android на java возможно запустить функцию в бесконечном цикле без пересоздания и обновления всего activity?

Tags: java, android

```
// переменные таймера и его интервал:
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable;
int delay = 10000;


// создание activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    
    // вызов даже пустого цикла while вызывает закрытие приложения:
    boolean isInfinite;
    isInfinite = true;

    while(isInfinite) {

        //вызов таймера:
    handler.postDelayed(runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        
        // название функции:
            userInfo();
        }
    }, delay); }
```

Comment: ну так в коде вроде нет ничего, что намекало бы на цикл

Comment: создайте цикл и запустите код в нем.

Comment: да вот и проблема, в таймере все ок, но однократно... а вот когда эта же функция в цикле, приложение даже не запускается, как по грамотному ее в цикле и с задержкой сюда вставить?

Comment: Начнем с того для каких целей? Создайте поток и зацикливайтесь там.

Comment: Цель - автообновление полей из базы не перезагружая активити

Answer (score 0):

Что-то в этом духе:

```
boolean isInfinite;
  isInfinite = true;
  while(isInfinite) {
    yourFunction()
}
```

Comment: Когда вставляю подобный цикл в onCreate без функции или с функцией, то приложение вообще не запускается. Как его корректно написать в onCreate?